# Browserify - JsSip

Tags: node.js, browserify, sip, gulp-browser-sync, jssip

I have a new project where I'm using browserify to convert node modules into an sdk that can run inside the browser.

I'm requiring a number of other npm packages like:

```
var log4js = require('log4js');
```

That run fine and give me no problems in the browser, however JsSip just will not cooperate.  When I do

```
var JsSIP = require('jssip');
```

I get

> plivowebsdk.js:2 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../../package.json'

Looking through the code, it's obvious when it makes this call

```
var pkg = require('../../package.json');
```

is where it bombs out. Clearly it cannot find the package.json file, which it uses to pull out version information.  I know JsSip is actually built with browersify itself (or used to be) so that it can run in either node or a browser. Is this causing a conflict?

Still sort of new to browserify, is their a configuration option or transformation I can perform to get around this?

Comment: Given that `npm install jssip` fails, I'd suggest [raising an issue](https://github.com/versatica/JsSIP/issues) - if the version that was published yesterday won't install, that's a pretty major problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the be browserify errors, re did the build process using the gulp recipes for browersify and works as expected.